# Проблема с библиотекой unitypack

Tags: python, visual-studio

Хотел скачать библиотеку unitypack, получил ошибку о том что требуется Visual Studio C++ не меньше 14 версии или что-то вроде этого. Скачал Visual Studio Build Tools, теперь ошибка другая и не понятная.

```
Collecting unitypack
  Using cached unitypack-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting decrunch (from unitypack)
  Using cached decrunch-0.4.0.post1.tar.gz (83 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: fsb5 in c:\users\alisher\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from unitypack) (1.0)
Collecting lz4 (from unitypack)
  Using cached lz4-4.3.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (99 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\alisher\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from unitypack) (9.4.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: decrunch
  Building wheel for decrunch (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'decrunch' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icrunch -IC:\Users\Alisher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\Alisher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" /EHsc /Tpcrn_decomp.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\crn_decomp.obj -std=c++11
      cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  warning D9002: Їа®ЇгбЄ ­ҐЁ§ўҐбв­®Ј® Ї а ¬Ґва  "-std=c++11"
      crn_decomp.cpp
      crn_decomp.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: string.h: No such file or directory,
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for decrunch
  Running setup.py clean for decrunch
Failed to build decrunch
ERROR: Could not build wheels for decrunch, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

У меня python 3.10.6 версии